# What does the title "Whose line is it anyway?" mean?

Tags: adverbs, meaning

*[Whose line is it anyway?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whose_Line_Is_It_Anyway?)* is a comedy show in which participants are given a theme and they are supposed to come up with an act according to the theme given to them.

According to Oxford Dictionary, one possible meaning of *anyway* is to ask a question,
like

> What are you doing here anyway?

but I am not able figure out the meaning of *anyway* in this expression. Maybe it is because I am not able to imagine the context it has been said in.

What is the explanation?

Answer (score 10):

As noted in the [History](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whose_Line_Is_It_Anyway%3F#History) section of wikipedia's article about the *[Whose Line Is It Anyway?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whose_Line_Is_It_Anyway%3F)* show,

> Indeed the title of the show itself is a comedic riposte to another radio show, *What's My Line*, merged with the title of a 1972 teleplay (and eventual theatrical play) *Whose Life Is It Anyway?*.

The adverb *[anyway](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/anyway#Adverb)* (with conjunctive sense “regardless; anyhow”) when used in questions like “Whose line is it anyway?” or “What are you doing here, anyway?”, has a sense of “other questions aside”.   That is, “What are you doing here, anyway?” is more or less equivalent to  “Ignoring other questions, what are you doing here?”

Answer (score 3):

*Anyway* in the context you provided, means *regardless of other things or leaving other things aside.* So *what are you doing here anyway?* means that I am not interested in whatever other things you are doing or may have. I just want to know what you are doing here.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the origin was a hoary theatrical anecdote about a play that had been running too long, so the actors completely forgot what to say in the middle of a scene. The prompter hissed the line, but was ignored; repeated it at increasing volume, and was asked by one actor "Yes, we heard you; but whose line is it anyway?"

Comment: I absolutely do not believe this origin, precisely because of the "anyway". In the context of the anecdote, "anyway" doesn't make sense: the identity of the actor is the whole point. Without the "anyway", the anecdote is perfectly believable, but has nothing to do with the title.